# How can you buy a Presto card upon arrival at Toronto's Billy Bishop Airport?

Tags: public-transport, payment-cards, toronto, ytz

I will be traveling to Toronto and flying into [Billy Bishop Airport](https://www.billybishopairport.com/). I will then want to take the streetcar to my hotel, but will of course need to pay for it. The TTC [says that I can do so](https://www.ttc.ca/Fares-and-passes) using either coins with exact change or with their "Presto" farecard, but I am flying in from the US and have not been to Toronto since the Presto card was introduced, and so I will have neither of those things upon arrival.

Can I use a credit card to buy a Presto card upon arrival, either in the airport itself or nearby the land side of the ferry terminal? If so, how and where? As of Google Street View's most recent imagery (June 2021), [there do not appear to be](https://goo.gl/maps/hb2GUH8o2u5YReAr7) any vending machines at the nearby streetcar stop itself.

Comment: Since I can't comment, but *can* answer: I will mention that the fare machines within the new streetcars were announced to allow credit/debit payments, and at first did have this capability. But it apparently was trouble-prone and as efforts to get it working properly all failed, it was announced the they'd simply give up on it.

Comment: It might be easier to simply have the correct change on hand (or be willing to give up the extra nickle or two by having a pocket full of quarters).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Even if there were a vending machine, you wouldn't have been able to buy the physical card, as only some stations on the GO Transit and UP Express (Toronto Pearson International Shuttle) support buying at a surface vending machine.
If there were a subway station, you would have been able too, though. ([link](https://www.prestocard.ca/en/about/get-a-presto-card))

According to the [site](https://www.prestocard.ca/en/find-an-outlet/customer-service-outlets) :

There is, though, a Shoppers Drug Marts, on the main Lake Short Blvd W ([Google Maps Link](https://maps.app.goo.gl/Vu412knyukUJ8zaLA)) (walking further after passing the streetcar station, crossing the boulevard) who should allow you to buy your Presto card.

From @DJClayworth in the comments :

> As well there is a free shuttle bus to Union Station, where you can definitely buy a Presto card.

Comment: As well there is a free shuttle bus to Union Station, where you can definitely buy a Presto card.

Comment: thanks! crossing my fingers that I get out of the airport in time to get to the drug store before it closes at 10pm.

Comment: @mlc As a 'Plan B' you could buy a coffee or something like that with USD cash and many places will accept it and give you the change in CAD (and you could ask for the coins you need- $3.25 for adults or $2.30 for Sr/Youth). Not the best exchange rate typically, but it's more hassles for the retailer.  Might need a $10 to get the adult fare for sure.

Comment: @mlc there's also another shoppers about 10 minutes' walk away (390 Queens Quay) that's open til midnight. Definitely no shortage of them in the city. The shuttle to Union is probably the way to go though

Comment: Thank you! My flight, as it happens, was a bit early, so I had no problem stopping by Shoppers Drug Mart and getting on the streetcar. For my trip, heading west from the airport, it was considerably faster than going back and forth to Union Station, but of course for many other trips it might not be.

Answer (score 7):

Nicholas's answer was correct and very helpful when written, but [since August 2023](https://www.thestar.com/news/gta/ttc-riders-can-finally-pay-by-tapping-bank-cards-more-than-a-decade-after-it/article_53752874-542c-53cb-b9a7-1de7f66fb838.html), transit riders in Toronto have been able to [pay their fares with a contactless credit or debit card](https://www.ttc.ca/riding-the-ttc/Updates/Pay-your-fare-with-your-debit-or-credit-card) directly and avoid the problem of trying to find a Presto card or coins.